# Getting grey spots on eye

Tags: modeling, mesh

Im getting these grey spots on my eye in the render preview. i read that i have to flip or recalculate normal but that doesnt chnage anything, i also tried to apply everything. I used a Outline addon, is it because of this ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the Solidify Modifier. There are two issues with it and the result is that the modifier creates the new geometry in exactly same place as the original geometry of the eye. So, you have overlapping faces with opposite normals.

Here the two issues:

1. The Vertex Group you are using for the outline is actually empty. So there's no effect.

once (1) is fixed:

2. Increase the Factor (below the Vertex Group in the modifier) at least a little bit, because when the Factor is at 0, the geometry that's not in the vertex group will still create new and overlapping faces.

After that, everything should work fine. :)